# Yet another 'could not find or load main class' error

Tags: java, classpath

I have done my due diligence with respect to this problem.  I have done searches on google and stackoverflow regarding this problem, and I have tried them all, and am still running into this problem.

I am on MS Windows 7 Enterprise.

I am running java 1.7.0.79.

I have a simple X.java file

```
package p;

public class X {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

I am compiling the class using "javac -classpath . X.java".

I have verified it creates a X.class file.

I try to run the program using:

```
java -classpath . p.X
```

I get the error "Error: Could not find or load main class p.X"

I have tried using a CLASSPATH environment variables, I have tried -classpath .\X.class, I have tried -cp .\X.class, I have tried -cp ., I have tried all combinations of those things.  Nothing seems to work.

Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class is in package `p` so `java` expects it to load from a subdirectory `p`.

Create a subdirectory `p`, move `X.class` into `p` and then run `java -classpath . p.X` again.

Answer (score 0):

you pleae try this example :

you go to your package folder.set your class path for your java class on the folder.

```
c:/p> set classpath = "c:/jdk/bin";

c:/p>javac x.java

c:/p>java x.java
```